# Pointer-events animation not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

Is there any way to make the next code in Safari? Safari doesn't detect the a tag after hover.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrap:hover a {
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: pointerEvent 0s linear forwards .5s;
}

@keyframes pointerEvent {
  100% {
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">  Demo </a>
</div>
```

I need to delay the pointer-event because the a tag is inside a div which has a transformation animation on hover. If I do not delay the event, I can click over the a tag before the transformation ends.
The specific problem is in the footer [here](http://vps719925.ovh.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I could not solve it only with CSS, I had to give up and add Javascript code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My Javascript solution:
4500 = animation-duration + animation-delay = 4.5 seconds
YOURCLASS = Classname of the animation-container
[0] = first occurrence of YOURCLASS

```
<script>

document.getElementsByClassName('YOURCLASS')[0].style.pointerEvents='none';

setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementsByClassName('YOURCLASS')[0].style.pointerEvents='YOURCLASS';}, 4500);

</script>
```